# How to pass image location as a prop to another component and use it in require method

Tags: react-native

I have two .js files. Second file renders a card component. I wish to call this component 3 times from the first file with different image locations as props to the second file and display the image through the require method in the second file.
Here is what I tried. 
First File

```
<CardContent
        dp= "'../images/1Dp.jpg'" />
<CardContent
        dp= "'../images/2Dp.jpg'" />
<CardContent
        dp= "'../images/3Dp.jpg'" />
```

Second File

```
const { dp } = props;
return(
  <Card>
    <CardItem>
      <Left>
        <Thumbnail source={require({dp})} /> 
      </Left>
    </CardItem>
  </Card>
);
```

Note: The image locations are w.r.t to the location of Second file.
Error: **require must have single string literal argument** (This is the error I get on running the app)

Answer (score 3):

Here is something you could try,

In the first file write the code as below:

```
<CardContent
        dp= {require('../images/1Dp.jpg')} />
<CardContent
        dp= {require('../images/2Dp.jpg')} />
<CardContent
        dp= {require('../images/3Dp.jpg')} />
```

Then in your second file, re-write as follows:

```
const { dp } = props;
return(
  <Card>
    <CardItem>
      <Left>
        <Thumbnail source={dp} /> 
      </Left>
    </CardItem>
  </Card>
);
```

I believe this should work. That is how i resolved this same issue.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You have a set of extra brackets in the Card component in your require call. You also have a set of extra commas when you pass `dp` as a prop. should be `<CardContent dp="../images/2Dp.jpg" />`

```
const { dp } = props;
return(
  <Card>
    <CardItem>
      <Left>
        <Thumbnail source={require(dp)} /> 
      </Left>
    </CardItem>
  </Card>
);
```

That should work.

In your code, you are using `{dp}` which is the es6 shorthand notation for `{dp:dp}`.
`require` takes a string as the first argument.

Comment: No I wrapped dp inside { } as it is a prop that I am using. Though even removing it gives the same error.

Comment: I don't know whether I am thinking right but I passed the location as a string. i.e when I do `<Text> {dp} </Text>` this is printed `'../images/1Dp.jpg'` along with the single quotes. So I assumed writing `{dp}` in require would translate to `<Thumbnail source={require('../images/1Dp.jpg')}` which works fine when hardcoded. Please correct if wrong.

Comment: When you do `<Text>{dp}</Text>`, it is jsx notation that let you tell react that  dp is a variable. But that is the same in `source={}`. Therefore you just need to write `dp` inside of it.

Comment: Ok I tried the changes you suggested, i.e removing the extra single quotes while passing as prop and the `{ }` in require but it still gives the same error.

Comment: You should look at what kind of props <Thumbnail> takes. Maybe you should pass it directly ‘dp’ and not the require function. Depends of what you should pass to ‘source’ but you could try ‘source={dp}’